# exiting for loop inside generate statement

Tags: verilog

I am trying using infinite for loop inside generate statement. But the problem is I cannot stop it or exit it using some condition. I used "disable" and "break". Both don't work.

It shows an error :

> unexpected token: 'disable'

Please help me solve this problem or suggest an alternative to it. Here is my Verilog code:

```
module top(a1,a3,wj,d4,d10,d2,dc,dtot);
input [11:0]a1,a3,wj;
input [3:0]d4;
input [9:0]d10;
input [1:0]d2;
input [25:0]dc;
output reg[25:0]dtot;

reg [25:0]dt,error;
reg [11:0]alpha1,alpha3;

genvar i;
generate

    for (i=1;i>0;i=i+1-1)begin:test
    assign a1[11:0]=alpha1[11:0];
    assign a3[11:0]=alpha3[11:0];

    calb_top t1(a1,a3,wj,d4,d10,d2,dc,dt,error,alpha1,alpha3);

    if(error==26'b00000000000000000000000000)begin
    disable test;
    //break;
    end

end
endgenerate         
assign dtot=dt;
endmodule
```

Answer (score 2):

Verilog `generate` block are used to describe physical hardware. As such, an inifinite loop in a `generate` block will require infinite resources.

Any `for` loop inside a `generate` statement must be of a fixed and finite size that can be determined during synthesis.

Remember that HDL is not executed sequentially, but describes connections between physical circuits. Since it appears that you only require one instance of the `calb_top` module, you don't require either the `generate` block or the `for` loop.

---

**Edit:**
Since you're intending to perform an iterative process, you have two options, as Greg pointed out in his comment below - you can either instantiate a fixed number of `calb_top` blocks (since an infinite number would require an infinite amount of space) or to re-use the same block some number of times.

Here are some samples. I've haven't sim'd or synthesized them, but they're logically correct.

**N-Block solution**

```
module top(a1,a3,wj,d4,d10,d2,dc,dtot,clock,done);

parameter NUM_BLOCKS = 10;

input [11:0]a1,a3,wj;
input [3:0]d4;
input [9:0]d10;
input [1:0]d2;
input [25:0]dc;
output [25:0]dtot;

wire [11:0] a1s [NUM_BLOCKS:0];
wire [11:0] a3s [NUM_BLOCKS:0];
wire [25:0] dt [NUM_BLOCKS-1:0];
wire [25:0] error [NUM_BLOCKS-1:0];

assign a1s[0]=a1;
assign a3s[0]=a3;

genvar i;
generate

    for (i=0;i<NUM_BLOCKS;i=i+1)begin:test
    calb_top t1(a1s[i],a3s[i],wj,d4,d10,d2,dc,dt[i],error[i],a1s[i+1],a3s[i+1]);

    end
endgenerate   

assign dtot=dt[NUM_BLOCKS-1];

endmodule
```

This links together a number of `calb_top` blocks equal to `NUM_BLOCKS`, then outputs the result of the final block to `dtot`. This doesn't do any checks on the error, so you may want to put in your own code to check `error[NUM_BLOCKS-1]` (the error of the final `calb_top`).

**Single-Block solution:**

```
module top(clock,start,a1,a3,wj,d4,d10,d2,dc,dtot);
input clock;
input start;
input [11:0]a1,a3,wj;
input [3:0]d4;
input [9:0]d10;
input [1:0]d2;
input [25:0]dc;
output reg[25:0]dtot;

wire [25:0]dt,error;
reg [11:0] a1in, a3in;
wire [11:0] alpha1,alpha3;

calb_top t1(a1in,a3in,wj,d4,d10,d2,dc,dt,error,alpha1,alpha3);

always @(posedge clock)
begin
    if (start)
    begin
        a1in <= a1;
        a3in <= a3;
    end
    else
    begin
        a1in <= alpha1;
        a3in <= alpha3;
    end
end

always @(posedge clock)
    if (start)
        dtot <= 0;
    else if (error == 0)
        dtot <= dt;
    else
        dtot <= dtot;


endmodule
```

Each clock cycle, we run one pass through `calb_top`. If `start` is 1, then `a1` and `a3` are used as inputs. Otherwise, the previous outputs `alpha1` and `alpha3` are used. When `error` is 0, then `dtot` is set. Note that I've added `clock` and `start` to the port list.

Comment: okay I got it. But i don't want only one instance of the calb_top module, instead I want to keep generating its instances untill the error becomes zero. This error is the output from calb_top module which I am using as a condition to exit the loop.

Comment: when `error` is zero, what signals are you looking to capture? Also, what's the prototype for `calb_top` (which signals are `input`s vs `output`s)?

Comment: @vishi, You cannot generate module instances until `error` is zero. `generate` must static unroll at compile time. `error` will not be evaluated until simulation. You must generate enough `calb_top` to resolve the worst case scenario. Worst case can require an unreasonable amount of hardware, and most of the logic will be under utilized. Using sequential logic will allow reuse of the `calb_top` instance by flopping the feedback.

Comment: @wilcroft when error is zero , i want to capture "dt" of the calb_top module. And following are the inputs and outputs of calb_top:   Inputs:- a1,a3,wj,d4,d10,d2,dc......outputs are:-dt, error, alpha1, alpha3......So, i want to stop the loop i.e. stop instantiating calb_top ......and dt will get assigned to dtot outside the generate statement.

Comment: @Greg thanks...I understood your point. Infinite generate is not possible

Comment: @vishi I've amended my original answer with some code snippets to demonstrate some possible solutions, depending on your needs.